# what will bw the output of this code? c++

Tags: c++, function, integer, output

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int f(int i){
  int k=0;
  if(i>0)
    {
        int k=i*10;
    }
    else {
        int k= i++;
    }
    cout <<k;
    return i;
}


int main()
{
    cout << f(1);
    cout << ".";
    cout << f(0);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code, compiler shows "01.01" which i quite don't understand, any help will be very much welcomed!

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. It is not possible to "help you" in an unspecified way, or address the fact that you "quite don't understand" - because we do not know what you don't understand about it, or *why* you don't understand it. Your question title asks what the output is, but you clearly have already run the code and seen what the output is. We need a clearer question than that.

Comment: What do *you* think the output *should be instead*? And *why*? If you don't have any particular idea about it, then how are we supposed to start explaining?

Comment: sorry i am new to this! i tried running the code as well as executing it by myself to try to see if i am correct! thing is the answer that i got was 101.01 instead of what the compiler showed! so i got pretty confused, hence why i asked

Comment: Okay, so you should try to talk through, step by step, how you expect that output to occur. Then you should [use a debugger](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+use+a+debugger) to learn what *actually* happens, step by step, and see where that differs from your expectation (that's what @Quimby meant). That will allow you to ask a *specific*, pointed question, and ideally to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the part of the code that works differently from your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int k = i * 10;` and `int k = i++;` are declarations of `k` that *shadow* the outer `k`. The statement `std::cout << k;` in the outer scope therefore always outputs zero.

The only effect of the `if` body is to increase `i` by 1. And it only does that if `i` is zero (or less). That value of `i` is returned printed.

Thus the output is `01.01`. Armed with a line by line debugger, the shadowing effect will be obvious.